P-Value not matching test statistic in Kolmogorov–Smirnov test (stats.kstest)
I am trying to learn how to use the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test in scipy (stats.kstest). For a simple problem like the example in the documentation, the test statistic for the one sample test seems to be correct, but the p-value does not make sense.
Here is an example where I run 5000 runs of the test statistic against randomly generated normally distributed data.
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pValues = []
statistics = []
for q in range(5000):
    F = stats.norm.rvs(size=5000)
    res = stats.kstest(F, stats.norm.cdf, alternative='two-sided')
    pValues.append(res.pvalue)
    statistics.append(res.statistic)

plt.close('all')
statistics = np.array(statistics)
statCritical = 1.36/(len(F)**0.5)
print(f'fraction above critical stat ({statCritical}): ',len(statistics[statistics>statCritical])/len(statistics))
print(f'fraction below critical stat ({statCritical}): ',len(statistics[statistics<statCritical])/len(statistics))
plt.hist(statistics,bins=50)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('hist.statistic.png')

plt.close('all')
pValues = np.array(pValues)
print('fraction above pvalue 0.95: ',len(pValues[pValues>0.95])/len(pValues))
print('fraction below pvalue 0.05: ',len(pValues[pValues<0.05])/len(pValues))
plt.hist(pValues,bins=50)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('hist.pvalue.png')

I got the value for the critical test statistic from here: https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~lipschultz/cs1538/prob-table_KS.pdf
When I run this I get that the fraction of test statistics above the critical value is ~0.05 and below the test statistic is ~0.95 (which is what I expected). The p-values that are returned are essentially uniform and random between 0 and 1. What am I missing?

It seems your procedure is OK. What are your expectation for the distribution of p-values? Why uniform distribution makes you doubt?

I would expect that there should be a direct relationship between the test statistic and the p-value. My samples are drawn from the same distribution as the reference so the test should tell me that. By chance, I would anticipate that sometimes the test gets it wrong, but the majority of the time it should correctly show that they come from the same distribution. When I run the test 5000 times in my example the test returns a random p-value between 1 and 0.

There is a clean relationship between statistic and pvalue (draw the scatter plot to convince you). I may be wrong, but I have the feeling that you think because the distribution is uniform the test fails more that it should, but this is not the case. In this scenario almost 5% of your test fails with a confidence value of 0.05 which is expected, and almost 95% of the test have pvalue >0.05 so you cannot reject H0.

Ah, that clarifies it. I think I misunderstood what the p-value meant for this test. Drawing the scatter plot shows the clear relationship between test statistic and the p-value. And as you said for 5% of the trials the test fails as anticipated. Thank you for your help.

Your procedure is correct and it reflects what you should expect.
With the following seed:
np.random.seed(12345)

As you noticed, at a certain level of confidence, H0 will be rejected (you chose confidence level of 95% so the critical probability is 0.05) in your calculations (D > 0.019233). That is, some drawn sample seems too far away from normality to trust at a certain confidence they actually have been drawn form normal.

Test with D statistic greater than your critical value leads to reject H0.
Now if we check how p-values are distributed, we confirm your observation it is almost certainly uniformly distributed:

Where the left observations are tests which reject H0 at the confidence level and right observations are tests which cannot reject H0 at the confidence level.
So, as expected at a confidence level x % we will reject (100 - x) % of H0. Hence the uniform distribution. In your case, almost 95% of your trials are accepted (H0 is not rejected) and almost 5% rejects H0.
Relationship between statistic and p-values can be visualized and confirm your independently computed critical value makes sense:

As you say, p-value are often difficult to interpret and their implementation may vary from software to another. In this case you can rely on the definition of Wikipedia:

In null-hypothesis significance testing, the p-value is the
probability of obtaining test results at least as extreme as the
result actually observed, under the assumption that the null
hypothesis is correct

Which is the same as implemented at least in scipy.stats.kstest (see bottom examples for more details).
